# Predict without saving intermediate states

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, predict

I've trained a (only-convs) network using small images patches, and now I am using it on larger images. Its working pretty well, except that when the image is much much larger, I end up getting out of memory.

**Is there a way to predict the output of the network without saving intermediate states (the ones used for computing the backward pass?)**.

I just need the output of the forward pass, and I have no use at all for the gradients of the backward pass (the network is already trained).

Ps: I've already tried to split the greater image into patches, but doing so breaks the spatial correlation (particularly on the borders of each patch).

Edit: I am posting the function (code in python) I use for predicting a given img. It takes the img, adjust to the proper shape and value range, predicts, and returns:

```
def predictImg(img_name,autoencoder):
   img = np.asarray(Image.open(img_name)).astype('float32')
   img2 = np.expand_dims(np.transpose(img.astype('float32')[:,:,:3],(2,0,1))/255.0,0)  # setting up for shape (sample,channels,x,y), ranging between [0,1]
   prediction = autoencoder.predict(img2)
   return np.transpose(np.round(np.clip(prediction[0]*255,0,255)),(1,2,0)) # getting a [0,255] image (discretized color values)
```

Comment: Not sure, but what if you gave patches a little greater than the area you want? Suppose you want a 100x100 result, you give a patch to get a 120x120 result and discard the borders?

Comment: Please show your code. How are you making predictions?

Comment: I think that `predict` doesn't save intermediate states, or compute gradients

Comment: If you could provide us a model definition - we could help you